# Override document mode settings programatically in IE

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer

I have done setting for document mode 8 manually for my web server in IE11. Now I am deploying one another tool at same server like webserver/apptool. For this also document mode is coming 8. I want to change document mode only for my app tool. Meta tag is not working at all. I have to run AngularJS 1.4.7 on this tool. What I can do?

Comment: I am not sure it is clear what you are asking. Are you stuck on a piece of JavaScript in Angular?

Comment: Hi, Enterprise Intranet apps can use 'Enterprise site mode lists' to control the IE11 emulation mode of their legacy intranet sites. For your AngjularJS app to run in the IE Intranet zone on a domain network, remove the x-ua headers from your server and allow it to assume 'Edge' emulation. Use the Emulation tab of dev tools to confirm that it does indeed default to 'Edge Mode' (by default) and does not assume a lower emulation mode from the Enterprise Site Mode lists of that company.

Comment: Always code to standards...(html5, ecma script) and use feature detection to gracefully fall back to polyfills on web browsers that do not support a feature.

Comment: If you app is hosted inside an iframe it will assume the Emulation mode of the top document. So in combination use File>Properties to determine which IE security zone a domain is mapped to and the Emulation tab to determine which IE Emulation mode is being used and how it was established.

Comment: I want to run my application untimately. Either by enabling angularjs in IE8 mode or by changing document mode to higher version. In IE8 mode it is giving error 'angular is not defined.' If I made angularjs work on IE8 still few component may cause issue to run on IE8, So I think it will be better if I can change document mode anyhow. But as document mode have been set via setting, it is not changing via meta tag.